# Placeholder text rendering differently in (Stripe?) iframe in Safari?

Tags: css, debugging, browser

I'm building a payment form based on [react-stripe-js](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js). The `PaymentElement` brings in all of the required payment fields in an `iframe`, but I need to add some other details to the form (e.g., Name, email address). The problem I'm having is that the placeholder text in the form fields renders differently for fields inside the `iframe` than for those outside, on Safari.

If I dig down into Safari's Web Inspector, and look at the Computed properties for the Shadow Content, it *thinks* it's using the User Agent Style Sheet "darkgray", but it shows it differently right next to the definition inside of the computed styles:

[image: computed vs. ... computed? color]

For fields in the same form but outside of the Stripe `iframe`, the ... I don't even know what to call these things. The "defined color" and "rendered defined color" are the same:

[image]

This doesn't appear to happen in either Chrome of Firefox. This is Safari 15.5.

What's causing this, and is there some way to fix it? Or how can I go about debugging it?